# ruby output question

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
File.open("/log/#{hostname}-#{@tdate}-errors.txt",'w') do |o|
  run=tn.cmd('String'=>'sh int', 'Match'=>/#/) { |c| puts c}
  run.each_line do |re|
    title = re.match /([\S]+)Ethernet\S+/
    rep = re.match /\d+ input errors/
    #o.puts run
    o.puts title
    o.puts rep 
   end
 end
 tn.close
```

It writes to a file just fine, but adds a bunch of spaces between title and rep. How do I get rid of the spaces?

Comment: What's `tn`? The sample looks to be incomplete.

Comment: Thats where I establish a telnet connection

Comment: What does typical output from the `telnet` command look like?

Comment: This is what I'm working with

Comment: 16673981 packets input, 5543583656 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 23686 broadcasts (11832 multicast)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     23021028 packets output, 7947141053 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

Comment: So where does the string "Ethernet" occur? What is the "title" regular expression supposed to be matching?

Comment: The file looks like this: GigabitEthernet3/1 0 input errors with multipe blank lines between GigabitEthernet3/1 and 0 input errors

Comment: Did either of the proposed answers help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try rstrip to remove trailing whitespace http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000822

Comment: not sure how to use rstrip with the code I have above. Any suggestions?

Comment: The file looks like this: GigabitEthernet3/1 0 input errors with multipe blank lines between GigabitEthernet3/1 and 0 input errors

Comment: `puts` will append a newline at the end of the string. I would recommend doing something like  `o.print title.rstrip + rep.rstrip`

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want to do something like this:

```
File.open("/log/#{hostname}-#{@tdate}-errors.txt",'w') do |o|
  run = tn.cmd('String'=>'sh int', 'Match'=>/#/) { |c| puts c}
  title = nil
  error_count = nil
  run.each_line do |line|
    title = $1 if line =~/(\S+Ethernet\S+)/
    error_count = Integer($1) if line =~ /(\d+) input errors/
  end
  title ||= 'no title'
  error_count ||= 0
  o.puts title
  o.puts error_count
end
tn.close
```

Comment: The file looks like this:                                                                  GigabitEthernet3/1






































0 input errors  with multipe blank lines between GigabitEthernet3/1 and 0 input errors